# R quantmod chartseries shifting a moving average to the left and right

Tags: r, quantmod

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2013-01-01", to=Sys.Date())
chartSeries(SPY, TA="addSMA(20)")
```

Is there a way of shifting a moving average to the left and right?

Comment: try maybe `s <- lag(SMA(SPY,20),10); chart_series(SPY); add_TA(s);`

Comment: Error in `index<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1357084800, 1357171200, 1357257600,  : 
  unsupported ‘index’ index type of class ‘POSIXct’ Thanks got error above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lag` is key here

```
s <- get(getSymbols('SPY'))
sma <- SMA(Cl(s),20)

chart_Series(s ,subset="2013::")
add_TA(sma , on = 1)
add_TA(lag(sma,10) , on = 1 , col ='red')
add_TA(lag(sma,-10) , on = 1 , col = 'blue')
```

outcome
[image]

Comment: Error in `index<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1357084800, 1357171200, 1357257600,  : 
  unsupported ‘index’ index type of class ‘POSIXct’ Thanks,I keep getting these errors and I do not know why

Comment: post your full code. it looks like your not using a valid xts object or something.

Comment: I just used the code above in your post (including library(quantmod) at the top). I think the POSIXct error means that it is not recognizing the dates but I am not really sure.

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be a timezone issue. checkout this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640133/coercing-a-posixct-object-to-date-object/15640388#15640388) - you might find it help full.